# Asus ROG Strix Scar II (GL504GW)

Tags: asus

I have installed Ubuntu 19.04 on laptop, and at the moment fans, are on minimum speed.
I have installed lm sensors module and scanned computer, it found only 6 temperature sensors from CPU (my guess from each core is one) and added them to the /etc/modules. There are no PWM sensors detected so when i try to run pwm-config this is the result:

## pwmconfig revision $Revision$ ($Date$)

This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

Anyone has some ideas how to sort this out?